# Get Document array counts by conditions, then join to another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two sample collections

1. Govenor Info
2. Region Info.

I want to:

1. display regions info
2. count regions and cities
3. join govenor info

I try 3 methods at the button of question. Each one needs one of my requirements. Hope someone can fill it.

NOTE. you can say why not govenor info in the same collection regionInfo. I have reason that "govenor" collection is connected with other collections as well. 
So, I need separate "govenor" collection.

govenor

```
[{
    "_id" : "007",
    "name" : {
        "fname" : "Joe",
        "lname" : "McDee",
            }
},
{
    "_id" : "008",
    "name" : {
        "fname" : "Martin",
        "lname" : "Neilwel",
             }
}]
```

regionInfo

```
{
  "country_id" : 328,
  "country_name" : "UK",
 }
  "regions" : [{

    "region_id" : 001,
    "region_name" : "west midlands",
    "govenor_id" : "007"
  },
                {
    "region_id" : 002,
    "region_name" : "east midlands"
    "govenor_id" : "008"
                }
  ],
   "cities" : [{
      "city_id" : 1,
      "region_id" : 001,
      "city_name" : "Birmingham"
    }, {
      "city_id" : 2,
      "region_id" : 001,
      "city_name" : "coventry"
    }, {
      "city_id" : 3,
      "region_id" : 001,
      "city_name" : "warsaw"
    },  {
      "city_id" : 4,
      "region_id" : 002,
      "city_name" : "dudley"
    },
     {
      "city_id" : 5,
      "region_id" : 002,
      "city_name" : "blabla"
    }]
}
```

Desired Result:

```
{ 
  "_id" : { "country_name" : "UK", "number_of_region" : 2 },
  "regions" : [
    {
      "region_name" : "west midlands",
      "govenor.fname" : "Joe",
      "cities_in_region" : 3
    },
    {
      "region_name" : "east midlands",
      "govenor.fname" : "Martin",
      "cities_in_region" : 2 
    }
  ]
}
```

I cannot find the count of cities with this:

```
db.collection('regionInfo').aggregate( [ 
  { '$unwind': "regionInfo" },  
  { '$lookup':{
    from: "govenor",
    localField: 'regionInfo.govenor_id',
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "Gjoin"
  }},
  { '$lookup': {
    from: "regionInfo",
    localField: 'regions.region_id',
    foreignField: "cities.gevenor_id",
    as: "govjoin"
  }},
  { '$project' : {
    R_id: "$regionInfo.region_name",
    govenor_fname:"$Gjoin..name.fname",
    govenor_lname:"$Gjoin.name.lname",
  }}
])
```

If I Use mapReduce, I can count cities(not right format) and not join govenor info

```
    map = function(){
    for (var index = 0; index < this.regions.length; ++index) {
            var auth = this.regions[ index ];
            emit( auth._id ,{cmt : {'this.cities.region_id' :'this.regions.region_id'}} );
        }}
    reduce = function(auth, counters) {
        count = 0;
        for (var index = 0; index < counters.length; ++index) {
            count += counters[index];
        }
        return count;
    }
```

This is My Fav Method by Neil Lunn. But I need to implement to join with govenor info:

```
db.collection.find().map(doc => ({ 
  _id: { 
    country_name: doc.country_name,
    number_of_regions: doc.regions.length
  }, 
  regions: doc.regions.map( r => ({ 
    region_name: r.region_name,
    cities_in_region: doc.cities.filter( c => 
      c.region_id === r.region_id ).length })
   )
```

}))

Comment: Well I wrote that because the data you presented originally appeared to actually be in "one document". But you were asked to clean up that question. Two collections is a different thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you basically want to follow the pattern of the basic "reshaping" statement I gave you first with a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage. Then you do the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on the `"regions"` array before you [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), since you need to do that as [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) cannot put output "inside" an array:

```
db.getCollection('regionInfo').aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "_id": {
      "country_name": "$country_name",
      "number_of_region": { "$size": "$regions" }
    },
    "regions": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$regions",
        "as": "r",
        "in": {
          "region_name": "$$r.region_name",
          "govenor_fname": "$$r.govenor_id",
          "cities_in_region": {
            "$size": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$cities",
                "as": "c",
                "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$c.region_id", "$$r.region_id" ] }
              }   
            }
          }
        }
      } 
    }  
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$regions" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "govenor",
    "localField": "regions.govenor_fname",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "regions.govenor_fname"
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "regions.govenor_fname": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$regions.govenor_fname.name.fname",
          0
        ]
      }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "regions": { "$push": "$regions" }    
  }}
])
```

For the first part it all takes place just within the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) as we are just changing the shape of the document, much as was demonstrated in the JavaScript example to simply reshape things.

The "counts" you want are actually achieved by getting the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) from the various arrays in the document. The first is a simple "size" of the `"regions"` array contained.

The second "count" of "cities" from within each "region" is done by using [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) on the `"cities"` array in order to match on the current "region". The filtered list is then also simply tested for "size".

Since `"regions"` is an "array" and we want to join to another collection, we need to "de-normalize" it first. The `$unwind` does this operation by creating a copy of the document for each array member.

The [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) can then reference the supplied `"govenor_id"` which we actually renamed to the target field in the earlier stage. We renamed it there so the order in the result document does not change around.

Since the result of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) is also an array ( since it can possibly match many ), we know it's a `1:1` relation here so instead of doing anything else we simply get the first array index from the result with [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/).

That happens withing the [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) pipeline stage that allows us to "only specify **'new'** fields instead of all of them. This is added in MongoDB 3.4, but in an earlier version ( 3.2 since we use `$lookup` ) we would need to specify all fields explicitly using [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/).

All that remains now is to bring the document(s) back together, in the state before the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), so we use the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage in order to "group" by the document `_id` and [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) all the `"regions"` data back into an array form.

The output is then:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "country_name" : "UK",
        "number_of_region" : 2
    },
    "regions" : [ 
        {
            "region_name" : "west midlands",
            "govenor_fname" : "Joe",
            "cities_in_region" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "region_name" : "east midlands",
            "govenor_fname" : "Martin",
            "cities_in_region" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Also fixed your data since it had formatting errors in several places. The `"govenor"` collection stays the same:

**regionInfo**

```
{
    "country_id" : 328.0,
    "country_name" : "UK",
    "regions" : [ 
        {
            "region_id" : 1.0,
            "region_name" : "west midlands",
            "govenor_id" : "007"
        }, 
        {
            "region_id" : 2.0,
            "region_name" : "east midlands",
            "govenor_id" : "008"
        }
    ],
    "cities" : [ 
        {
            "city_id" : 1.0,
            "region_id" : 1.0,
            "city_name" : "Birmingham"
        }, 
        {
            "city_id" : 2.0,
            "region_id" : 1.0,
            "city_name" : "coventry"
        }, 
        {
            "city_id" : 3.0,
            "region_id" : 1.0,
            "city_name" : "warsaw"
        }, 
        {
            "city_id" : 4.0,
            "region_id" : 2.0,
            "city_name" : "dudley"
        }, 
        {
            "city_id" : 5.0,
            "region_id" : 2.0,
            "city_name" : "blabla"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much  Neil Lunn, It works perfectly what I wanted. You save my days. I really appreciate your time, knowledge and detail explaination.
Thnaks for reformatting question as well. I used stackoverflow but I don't have good experiences for questioning.
 Let me say again thank you.

Have a great life !!!

Comment: in you query find().map(). In this part `code`  $filter (c.region_id === r.region_id ), for me _id doesn't work with ObjectId("123abc") , it works with only string "123abc" without ObjectId.  
I try with  " var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID " and " _id:ObjectID(_id)" but not work.
I have to find out this solution why ObjectId has that problem. 
By the way I really like the query which you gave me. It is also very useful in others places.

Comment: I want to upvote but I don't have enough reputation. I will do it when I have it.